# How do I combine these SQL queries to give me one result?

Tags: mysql, sql

Using MySQL, I have multiple DB tables which contain the same structure/column names, but different data. I can get all relevant data from a **Table 1** by using the following query:

```
SELECT heading, COUNT( * ) AS number FROM TABLE1
WHERE category = 'PARENT'
GROUP BY heading ORDER BY number DESC
```

I can get all the relevant data from **Table 2** with this:

```
SELECT heading, COUNT( * ) AS number FROM TABLE2
WHERE category = 'PARENT'
GROUP BY heading ORDER BY number DESC
```

This carries on, with TABLE3, TABLE4 etc

How can I combine the queries so that I have 1 query and one result? Instead of a separate result for each table?

I've tried placing UNION between the queries, but it's not giving me the result I want...

Comment: What is wrong with `UNION`?

Comment: A `union` does indeed horizontally combine the results of 2+ queries so long as they have the same number of columns of the same type. Explain how it is not giving you the result you want. As an FYI, `union` as opposed to `union all` will discard duplicates, were any table to have the same heading value and the same count.

Comment: The problem with union is that it's not clear from the where to do the grouping. Do you need to union everything, and then group and count, or do you need to group and count with each table, and then union?

Comment: Depends on what you want but generally I'd say use `UNION` to combine two `SELECT`'s and SELECT and group afterwards from the result.

Comment: It's the count that's not working. Whether I use UNION or UNION ALL the count is only appearing as the count of the second table

Comment: With the `union` or `union all` you do the `GROUP BY` in both queries, and the `ORDER BY` in the last query.

Comment: This depends of course on whether you want the aggregate count of all tables added up or the aggregate per each table on a separate row.

Comment: @Brian DeMilia - I want the aggregate count of all tables added up

Comment: Then the answer posted by avk is what you want.

Comment: @Brian DeMilia Thank you for the pointer. Got it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Union All" your queries but put the entire query in a subselect. Then do this:

```
Select heading
,            sum(number)
from ( [your queries with union all] )
group by heading
```

Answer (score 1):

You can select from the `UNION` and `GROUP` and `ORDER` on its result:

```
SELECT heading, COUNT(*) AS number
  FROM (SELECT heading FROM TABLE1
         WHERE category = 'PARENT'
         UNION -- or UNION ALL - see comment below
        SELECT heading FROM TABLE2
         WHERE category = 'PARENT')
 GROUP BY heading ORDER BY number DESC;
```

***p.s.*** this one assumes that you want to count and group all rows except those from `TABLE2` which are already in `TABLE1`. Use `UNION ALL` in the snippet above if you want to count doublets as well.

***Alternatively*** (as per added comment above):

```
SELECT heading, SUM(number) AS number
  FROM (SELECT heading, COUNT(*) AS number FROM TABLE1
         WHERE category = 'PARENT'
         UNION -- or UNION ALL - see comment below
        SELECT heading, COUNT(*) AS number FROM TABLE2
         WHERE category = 'PARENT')
 GROUP BY heading ORDER BY number DESC;
```

Comment: #1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias ?

Comment: No sorry, not in this case. A copy and paste error. If column names are equal, you can omit the `AS ...` clause. Will fix the statement above ...